# Organizing projects/solutions in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am currently working on a project in Visual Studio 2010.

Right now, my solution explorer looks like:

[image]
In other projects, I've seen different components of the program split up into different class libraries, so one would have for example: `Project, Project.Data, Project.Business, etc` and the data would include the database context and repositories, and the business would contain the logic, etc.

How should I organize my project/solution? Is there a "best practice" I should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have everything in one project.  I would create two new projects in this solution:

```
CMv2.Data
CMv2.Services
```

And move those folders from your current project to the new projects.  I would rename `CMv2` to something like `CMv2.Web`

Comment: Thanks, Martin. In addition, should I move `Models` to its own project? That folder includes IRepositories and class objects (like `User` for example).

Comment: Your repositories should be in your Data project ... yes.  If you have ViewModels (models that are only used for your MVC views), leave those in the Web project, but move all Data and Database related items to your Data project ... also, if you want really separate concerns, you can move the Repositories to their own project - CMv2.Data.Repositories